# Shopware 6, jest test: [vuex] module namespace not found in mapState():

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, vuex, vue-test-utils, shopware6

My component test failed by commit to a custom state store with:
`[vuex] module namespace not found in mapState(): MyComponentStore/`

The component itself works as expected.

The codes:

tests/**myComponent.spec.test**

```
import { shallowMount, createLocalVue } from '@vue/test-utils';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
...
async function createWrapper() {
    const localVue = createLocalVue();
    localVue.use(Vuex);
    return shallowMount(await Shopware.Component.build('my-component'), {
        localVue,
        ...,
    });
}
describe('MyComponent', () => {
    let wrapper;
    
    beforeEach(async () => {
        wrapper = await createWarapper();
    });
    
    afterEach(() => {
        wrapper.destroy()
    });

    it('should be a Vue.js component', () => {

        Shopware.State.registerModule('MyComponentStore', {
            namespaced: true,
            state: {
                listEntity: [
                    {
                        id: 'entity_0'
                    }
                ]
            },
            mutations: {
                setLoading: jest.fn()
            }
        })

        expect(wrapper.vm).toBeTruthy();
    });

}
```

**myComponentStore.js**

```
export default {
    namspaced: true,
    state() {
        return {
            listEntity: [],
            loading: {
                list: false
            }
        }
    },
    mutations: {
        ...
        setLoading(state, value) {
            const name = value[0];
            const data = value[1];

            if (typeof data !== 'boolean') {
                return false;
            }

            if (state.loading[name] !== undefined) {
                state.loading[name] = data;
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        },
    }
}
```

myComponent/**template.html.twig**

```
<sw-container>
    <sw-number-field :value="computedTotal(i)"></sw-number-field>
</sw-container>
```

myComponent/**index.js**:

```
import template from './template.html.twig'
...
const { Component, Mixin } = Shopware;
const { Criteria } = Shopware.Data;
const { mapPropertyErrors, mapState, mapGetters } = Component.getComponentHelper();

Component.register('my-component', {
    ...
    computed: {
        ...mapState('MyComponentStore', [
            'listEntity',
            ...
        ]),
        computedTotal() {
           return (i) => this.__handleTotal(i)
        },
    },
    methods: {
        __handleTotal(i) {
            // calc total
            ...,
            // TODO enable after test fix
            Shopware.State.commit('MyComponentStore/setLoading', ['list', true])
            ...
            Shopware.State.commit('MyComponentStore/setLoading', ['list', false])
        }
    }

}
```

If i comment out the commit action in method `__handleTotal()`, the test pass without errors.

Looking for answers, always a the **key `namespaced` is mentioned, but the key is set**.

Question:

- **What means the error** `[vuex] module namespace not found in mapState():`?
- **How to configure a (custom) store inside a jest component test**

**EDIT #1**

according to the answer by @dneustadt:

> Alternatively you could obviously just import your actual store and use it instead.

tests/**myComponent.spec.test**

```
...
import myComponentStore from './../state/my.component-store';
...

async function createWrapper() {
    const localVue = createLocalVue();
    localVue.use(Vuex);

    const store = new Vuex.Store({
        modules: {
            MyComponentStore: myComponentStore
        }
    });

    return shallowMount(..., {
        ...,
        mocks: {
           $store = store
        }
    })

}

describe(..., () => {
   ...,
   it('should be a Vue.js component', () => {
       expect(wrapper.vm).toBeTruthy();
   });

   it('should update total', () => {
       const list = [
           {id: 1}
       ]
       wrapper.vm.$store.commit(
           'MyComponentStore/setListEntity',
           list
       )
    
       console.log(wrapper.vm.listEntity)

   })
})
```

This configuration **threw another error** and print a empty `listEntity` (although all tests were green):

```
...
  console.log
    {}

      at Object.log (test/component/view/myComponent.spec.js:108:17)

  console.error
    [vuex] unknown mutation type: MyComponentStore/setLoading

      27 |     state._registerProperty('get', (name) => store.state[name]);
      28 |     state._registerGetterMethod('getters', () => store.getters);
    > 29 |     state._registerProperty('commit', (...args) => store.commit(...args));
...
  at VueComponent.commit (src/component/view/myComponent/index.js:172:28)
```

myComponent/**index.js:172:28**

```
Shopware.State.commit('MyComonentStore/setLoading', ['list', true])
```

Above the commit at `myComponent/index.js:172:28` i set a `console.log` to **check the `state.mutations`**.
myComponent/**index.js**

```
...
console.log(Shopware.State)
Shopware.State.commit('MyComonentStore/setLoading', ['list', true])
```

The log print **difference between `test environment` and `dev environment`**:

- `dev environment`: log prints mutations as expected (include `MyComponentStore/setLoading` or `swProductDetail/*` )
- `test environment`: there is no mutation like `MyComponentStore/setLoading`

the log on
**test environment**

```
_mutations: [Object: null prototype] {
          'notification/setThreshold': [Array],
          'notification/setWorkerProcessPollInterval': [Array],
          'notification/setNotificationsForCurrentUser': [Array],
          'notification/clearNotificationsForCurrentUser': [Array],
          'notification/clearGrowlNotificationsForCurrentUser': [Array],
          'notification/setNotifications': [Array],
          'notification/upsertNotification': [Array],
          'notification/removeNotification': [Array],
          'notification/setAllNotificationsVisited': [Array],
          'notification/upsertGrowlNotification': [Array],
          'notification/removeGrowlNotification': [Array],
          setCurrentUser: [Array],
          removeCurrentUser: [Array],
          setAdminLocale: [Array],
          registerAdminLocale: [Array],
          'adminMenu/clearExpandedMenuEntries': [Array],
          'adminMenu/expandMenuEntry': [Array],
          'adminMenu/collapseMenuEntry': [Array],
          'adminMenu/collapseSidebar': [Array],
          'adminMenu/expandSidebar': [Array],
          'adminMenu/setAdminModuleNavigation': [Array],
          'licenseViolation/setViolations': [Array],
          'licenseViolation/setWarnings': [Array],
          'licenseViolation/setOther': [Array],
          'licenseViolation/removeViolations': [Array],
          'licenseViolation/removeWarnings': [Array],
          'licenseViolation/removeOther': [Array],
          'context/setApiApiPath': [Array],
          'context/setApiApiResourcePath': [Array],
          'context/setApiAssetsPath': [Array],
          'context/setApiAuthToken': [Array],
          'context/setApiInheritance': [Array],
          'context/setApiInstallationPath': [Array],
          'context/setApiLanguage': [Array],
          'context/setApiApiVersion': [Array],
          'context/setApiLiveVersionId': [Array],
          'context/setApiSystemLanguageId': [Array],
          'context/setAppEnvironment': [Array],
          'context/setAppFallbackLocale': [Array],
          'context/setAppFeatures': [Array],
          'context/setAppFirstRunWizard': [Array],
          'context/setAppSystemCurrencyId': [Array],
          'context/setAppSystemCurrencyISOCode': [Array],
          'context/setAppConfigAdminWorker': [Array],
          'context/setAppConfigBundles': [Array],
          'context/setAppConfigVersion': [Array],
          'context/setAppConfigVersionRevision': [Array],
          'context/addAppValue': [Array],
          'context/addApiValue': [Array],
          'context/addAppConfigValue': [Array],
          'context/setApiLanguageId': [Array],
          'context/resetLanguageToDefault': [Array],
          'error/addApiError': [Array],
          'error/removeApiError': [Array],
          'error/resetApiErrors': [Array],
          'error/addSystemError': [Array],
          'error/removeSystemError': [Array],
          'settingsItems/addItem': [Array],
          'shopwareApps/setApps': [Array],
          'shopwareApps/setSelectedIds': [Array],
          'extensionEntryRoutes/addItem': [Array],
          'marketing/setCampaign': [Array],
          'extensionComponentSections/addSection': [Array],
          'extensions/addExtension': [Array],
          'tabs/addTabItem': [Array],
          'menuItem/addMenuItem': [Array],
          'modals/openModal': [Array],
          'modals/closeModal': [Array],
          'extensionMainModules/addMainModule': [Array],
          'actionButtons/add': [Array],
          'ruleConditionsConfig/setConfig': [Array],
          'sdkLocation/addLocation': [Array]
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

> How to configure a (custom) store inside a jest component test?

You may want to mock the store in your wrapper. This is a common practice to assert changes to the store, e.g. by having the setters/getters wrapped in `jest.fn()` and asserting they have been called with an expected value.

```js
async function createWrapper() {
    const localVue = createLocalVue();
    localVue.use(Vuex);
    return shallowMount(await Shopware.Component.build('my-component'), {
        localVue,
        mocks: {
            $store: new Vuex.Store({
                modules: {
                    MyPluginStore: {
                        namespaced: true,
                        state: () => ({
                            loading: {
                                list: false,
                            },
                        }),
                        mutations: {
                            setLoading(state, loading) {
                                state.loading = loading;
                            },
                        },
                    },
                },
            }),
        },
    });
}
```

Alternatively you could obviously just import your actual store and use it instead.

Comment: please take a look on my EDIT #1